# First time using preparedStatement, and it keeps sending me an exception. code review

Tags: java, sql

i'm getting an exception on this part of the code, and a cant figure out why, can some help me, please? thanks already.

```
pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO ENDERECO (ENDERECO,CIDADE,CEP,BAIRRO) VALUES (?,?,?,?) ",  
                        PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
            pstmt.setString(++i, endereco.getEndereco());
            pstmt.setString(++i, endereco.getCidade());
            pstmt.setString(++i, endereco.getCep());
            pstmt.setString(++i, endereco.getBairro());
            pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: What is the exception you are getting?  Please post it in the question.

Comment: Without the actual exception this is not a real question.

Answer (score 2):

Stacktrace is needed to identify the problem. But in any case I suggest to change your code as

```
        pstmt.setString(1, endereco.getEndereco());
        pstmt.setString(2, endereco.getCidade());
        pstmt.setString(3, endereco.getCep());
        pstmt.setString(4, endereco.getBairro());
```

i++ looks weird here

Comment: it is unhelpful to use a variable here. but since it uses ++i, not i++, then (assuming i is initialized to 0) this shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: Right, will correct my answer

Comment: tried, didn't work, i will try to upload the code to the code google. but thanks anyway.

Comment: You could first add exception stacktrace to your question, maybe that would be enough

Comment: Just because you think something 'looks weird' isn't a reason to change it, and it certainly doesn't answer the question. The only part that is even relevant is the first sentence, which should be a comment.